# WSO2 API Manager Consume Error While Caching is enabled

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I enable Caching for an API and try to consume it, I receive the response code error 500 with a description - "Error while building message". The response works fine when Caching is turned off. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the APIM version that you use? and also update the question with the full error log that you get

Comment: I am using AM version 1.9.0

Comment: In the log file, I received 4 errors - here is the first: 
  2016-05-11 05:44:32,882 #toXml. Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input. Error>>> java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol: END_OBJECT  More 
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-05-11 05:44:32,882] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} - #toXml. Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input. Error>>> java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol: END_OBJECT

Comment: second -   2016-05-11 05:47:54,916 Error building message  More 
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-05-11 05:47:54,916] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder} - Error building message org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:207) org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)

Comment: third -   2016-05-11 05:47:54,918 Error while building Passthrough stream  More 
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-05-11 05:47:54,918] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:207) org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)

Comment: fourth -   2016-05-11 05:47:54,918 Error while building message  More 
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-05-11 05:47:54,918] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - Error while building message org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:236) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:111) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)

Comment: can you put this is in the question. You can edit your question and out the log there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be occurred if you are passing a empty value to the request body for a POST request. Because the default JSON builder trying to convert JSON to XML and you can see this error when converting an empty message.

If you are sending a empty body for a post request change the builder and formatter to JsonStreamBuilder and JsonStreamFormatter using following steps.

1) Open axis2.xml which is in (APIM_HOME)/repository/conf/axis2 folder and comment the default JSON builder and formatter.

```
<!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder"/-->

<!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonFormatter"/-->
```

2) Un-comment the JsonStreamBuilder and JsonStreamFormatter.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```